# Fourier Transform Integration

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a Fourier transform to complete with the definition of the Fourier Transform.

Let $\phi$ be defined as follows.
$$\tag{1} \phi(x) = Ne^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}}e^{ik_0x} $$

I must complete the Fourier transform of the function.

The definition of a Fourier transform is as follows.

$$\tag{2} \hat f(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x) e^{-ikx}dx $$

To compute the Fourier transform we must evaluate the following integral with $\phi$ substituted into (2).

$$\tag{3} \hat\phi(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \phi(x) e^{-ikx}dx $$

$$\tag{4} \hat\phi(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int Ne^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}}e^{ik_0x} e^{-ikx}dx $$

I have tried completing this integral with completion of squares. I cannot find a way to finish this integral. How can I solve this integral?

Comment: You were correct to pursue completing the square.  You will need to evaluate a Gaussian integral thereafter.  And to be rigorous, you need to deform the contour back to the real line by appealing to Cauchy's Integral Theorem.   And that is about it.

Comment: After completing the square, $\hat\phi$ will become the following integral.


$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int Ne^{-(x-\frac{2x_0 + ik_0a^2}{2}}e^{\frac{(2x_0+ik_0a^2)^2}{2}} e^{\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}}dx$$

Comment: There is an error in the previous comment. $\hat\phi$ will be defined as follows.


$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int Ne^{-(x-\frac{2x_0 + ik_0a^2}{2})^2}e^{\frac{(2x_0+ik_0a^2)^2}{2}} e^{\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}}dx$$

Comment: After evaluating the Gaussian integral $\hat\phi$ is defined as follows.


$$\hat\phi(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int e^{\frac{(2x_0+ik_0a^2)^2}{2}} e^{\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}}dx$$

Comment: I substituted $u = x-\frac{(2x_0 + ik_0a^2)}{2}$ in.
After squaring both sides and changing the integral to polar coordinates, I found that the integral evaluated to $\sqrt{\pi}$.

This equation I have arrived at does not match the provided solution. I may have made an error in evaluating the Gaussian integral.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, enforce the substitution $x-x_0\to x$ so that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-\frac1{\alpha^2}(x-x_0)^2-i(k-k_0)x}\,dx&=e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-\frac1{\alpha^2}x^2-i(k-k_0)x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Then, enforce the substitution $x/\alpha\to x$ so that

$$e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-\frac1{\alpha^2}x^2-ikx}\,dx=\alpha e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-x^2-i(k-k_0)\alpha x}\,dx$$

Completing the square reveals

$$\alpha e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-x^2-i(k-k_0)\alpha x}\,dx=\alpha e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-((k-k_0)\alpha/2)^2}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-(x-i(k-k_0)\alpha /2)^2}\,dx$$

Enforcing the substitution $x-i(k-k_0)\alpha/2\to x$ yields

$$\begin{align}\alpha e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-((k-k_0)\alpha/2)^2}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-(x-i(k-k_0)\alpha /2)^2}\,dx&=\alpha e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-((k-k_0)\alpha/2)^2}\\\\
&\times \int_{-\infty-i(k-k_0)\alpha/2 }^{\infty-i(k-k_0)\alpha/2} e^{-x^2}\,dx\end{align}$$

Applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we can deform the contour back onto the real line to obtain

$$\alpha e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-((k-k_0)\alpha/2)^2}\int_{-\infty-i(k-k_0)\alpha/2 }^{\infty-i(k-k_0)\alpha/2} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\alpha e^{-((k-k_0)\alpha/2)^2}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx}_{=\sqrt\pi}$$

Putting it all together, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-\frac1{\alpha^2}(x-x_0)^2-i(k-k_0)x}\,dx=\alpha e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\sqrt\pi e^{-((k-k_0)\alpha/2)^2}$$

Comment: I think the same techniques you've applied in your solution can be applied to the original problem. I think you have misread the problem statement. 

You have two exponentials with $(x-x_0)$ in both. Please note in the original problem statement that one exponential contains $(k-k_0)$

Comment: Jeremy, I edited on 20 November in response to your posted comment herein.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And feel free to both up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.   Happy holidays!  -Mark

Comment: Please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  And Happy Holidays!

Comment: Your solution is incorrect by a factor of $\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @Jeremy Why do you say that?

Comment: I don't understand your first substitution. The term $e^{-i(k-k_0)x}$ is brought out of the integral as $e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}$

Comment: $e^{-i(k-k_0)(x+x_0)}=e^{-i(k-k_0)x}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}$

Comment: Make the substitution $x-x_0=t$.  Then, we have $e^{-i(k-k_0)x}=e^{-i(k-k_0)(t+x_0)}=e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\,e^{-i(k-k_0)t}$.  Now make the substitution $t=x$.  As for the factor of $\frac1{\sqrt 2}$, note that I have not divided the integral by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Comment: This problem comes from an assignment for a free class and I have contacted the professors to ask if I can obtain a copy of the solutions I was referencing. If I cannot obtain the set I will be unable to verify your solution's validity. The problem set solution has been removed. Your response did not match the problem set solution.

The substitution of $x-x_0 -> x$ may alter the original problem.

Comment: The substitutions you are attempting aren't a method explained in the problem set solution. The substitutions may nullify the validity of the equalities. 

For example, following "First, enforce the substitution x−x0→x so that", there is an extra term brought outside the integrand. $e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}$

Can you explain?

Comment: @Jeremy If we enforce the substitution $x-x_0\mapsto x$, this implies that $x\mapsto x+x_0$ and hence, we have

$$e^{-\frac1{\alpha^2}(x-x_0)^2-i(k-k_0)x}\mapsto e^{-\frac1{\alpha^2}x^2-i(k-k_0)(x+x_0)}=e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\,e^{-\frac1{\alpha^2}x^2-i(k-k_0)x}$$